# What is the point of this function in the Google Maps API tutorial?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

In this tutorial teaching how to place markers in the map: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3
there is a doNothing() function which is used in:

```
request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
```

What is the point of this function/line? Is it just to demonstrate that you can add any functions you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some bugs where it may happen that a readystatechange-event with readystate 4 fires multiple times(see e.g. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=159827)

Assigning the empty function prevents the original callback from getting executed multiple times in the browsers affected by this bug.

Answer (score 0):

There is no purpose for it. It's a dummy example function. (Ha! So I thought. See Dr. Molle's anwer for a correction.)

But are you using jQuery? If you are, you don't need that `downloadUrl()` function anyway. You can use jQuery's `$.get()` or `$.ajax()` function instead. Where you see code like this:

```
downloadUrl( "phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    // do stuff with xml
});
```

You can change it to:

```
$.get( "phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(xml) {
    // do stuff with xml
}, "xml" );
```

As a side note, it's really unfortunate that that Google Maps XML tutorial has never been updated to use JSON instead of XML. If you're generating the XML from your server, it's just as easy to generate JSON instead, and it's *much* easier to work with JSON instead of XML in the JavaScript code.

Comment: I am using xml because I am accessing my database.

Comment: Yes, but accessing the database doesn't have anything to do with what format you use to generate the output. You can use PHP to generate JSON from a database just as easily as you can generate XML. For example, in that tutorial code you would change the loop at the end to create a PHP array and then call `json_encode()` on that array. http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php